# Need help writing this function in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to represent this code in python3 it's written in python 2

```
    def transform(x, y , (a, b, c, d, e, f)=matrix):
        return a*x + b*y + c, d*x + e*y + f
```

**error**

```
def transform(x, y , (a, b, c, d, e, f)=matrix):
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

many more is coming

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just did. Learn something new every day :)

Answer (score -2):

```
def transform(x, y, matrix):
    (a, b, c, d, e, f) = matrix
    return a*x + b*y + c, d*x + e*y + f
```

Comment: Please note that: 1. code-only answers aren't considered useful; 2. if posting self-answered questions you can post Q & A simultaneously; and 3. you still need to do basic checking for dupes etc. before posting.